# How to change State in other component same level with parameter?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have ParentComponent

```
render(){ 
  return('<'Child1Component/> '<'Child2Component/>)
}
```

So, I'm in Child2Component how to change State in Child1Componet with parameter. It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call one method of parent from child1 , and this method will call another method of child2 using `refs`

add this to your parent component

```
onPressSuccess = params => {
this.refs.ComponentTwo.componentTwoMethod(params);
};
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <ComponentOne onPressSuccess={this.onPressSuccess}> ... </ComponentOne>
    <ComponentTwo ref={"ComponentTwo"}> ... </ComponentTwo>
  </View>
);
}
```

In `<ComponentOne>` call `this.props.onPressSuccess(params)` where `params` is parameters you want pass along with method.

here `componentTwoMethod` is a method in `<ComponentTwo>`, which can take params and set state or whatever you want to do.

Comment: Hi Jaydepp Galani! Child2Component is AppContainer! so how to component in rounter can get props from parent!